# Inequality with $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If x,y,z are positive real numbers and $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ prove that
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{1}{x^3+y^2+z}\le\frac{1}{xyz}.$$
I have tried to prove it this way:
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{1}{x^3+y^2+z}\le\frac{1}{xyz}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \sum_\text{cyc}\frac{xyz}{x^3+y^2+z}\le1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \sum_\text{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{yz}+\frac{y}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}}\le1$$
But we know that $$\frac{x^2}{yz}+\frac{y}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{yz}\cdot\frac{y}{xz}\cdot\frac{1}{xy}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{z^2y}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_\text{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{yz}+\frac{y}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}}\le\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{z^2y}}{3}$$
We now have to prove that $\sum_\limits\text{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{z^2y}}{3}\le1$.
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{z^2y}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2z}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{y^2x}}{3}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{1\cdot z^2\cdot y}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{1\cdot x^2\cdot z}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{1\cdot y^2\cdot x}}{3}$$
$$\le\frac{\frac{1+ z^2+ y}{3}+\frac{1+ x^2+ z}{3}+\frac{1+ y^2+ x}{3}}{3}=\frac{3+3+x+y+z}{9}$$
And the last part: $\;\dfrac{3+3+x+y+z}{9}\le1 \Leftrightarrow x+y+z\le3$ or
$$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\le \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}}$$ which is true.
I hope that it's correct. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I think your proof is right and very nice!

Also, we can use C-S:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^3+y^2+z}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y^2+z^3}{(x^3+y^2+z)(x+y^2+z^3)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y^2+z^3}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, by AM-GM

$$\frac{x^3+y^2+z}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{x^3y^2z}\implies \frac{1}{x^3+y^2+z}\le\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^2z}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{z^2y}}{3xyz}$$

thus

$$\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{1}{x^3+y^2+z}\le \sum_\text{cyc} \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^2z}}\le\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{z^2y}}{3xyz} \le 1$$

Comment: I think it's the ovetz13's solution exactly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg my idea was to simplify a little bit the first manipulation. I've added a different derivation for the key inequality.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Please let me know if it can work as a different solution now? Thanks!

Comment: I think now it's just wrong because Muirhead works for symmetric inequalities and can be wrong for cyclics.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!! I need to revise. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Michael forgive me, could you plese check my last solution! Thanks a lot I'm in debt with you!

Comment: No! For example, $\sum\limits_{cyc}z^2y\leq\sum\limits_{sym}z^2y$ it's $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2y-x^2z)\geq0$, which is $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\geq0,$ which is wrong. I think the ovetz13's solution is a best here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg what a disaster! I really need to improve my skills on inequalities! Thanks